NE555 as a timer or pulse generator
Hopefully this lands in the right place...
I have found a number of NE555 circuits but need to have some help with resistor and capacitor values and would like to know what values give two clock speeds, a 200ms pulse* cycle and in another application I need a 2,000ms clock pulse*.
Can someone kindly help with some values.
I need two time base options.
1st being 200ms pulses 2nd being 2000ms pulses
I found this circuit

As for the duty cycle itself, can this be set so that in a 200ms cycle the High atleast 20% of the cycle and in the 2,000ms, 10% is the high in the cycle.
Is there some sort of table that would tell me this info?
*pulse = meaning the complete cycle of low to high and back again at the desired interval. For example, if the 2000 ms clock cycle is desired, that means that the pulse is made up of 20ms Low to High and then 1980ms low until cycle repeats.

Please clarify and update up your question.  Your use of the word "pulse" is ambiguous.  What are the two output frequencies you want, and what is the duty cycle for each frequency?

Mark Giblin - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. || If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add (at least) the webpage name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). Always reference to the best of your ability - e.g. if the source was a research paper, give a proper citation for that paper (title, authors, publication etc), as well as its link. TY

the circuit above will give different results depending on the supply voltage and temperature.

Image is from this site

@MarkGiblin - Thanks for your reply. You said: "Image is from this site". If you meant Stack Exchange (and if there wasn't supposed to be a link to another site at the end of that comment) then the URL of the specific SE source page is still needed. In fact, the CC BY-SA license which allows you to copy material from elsewhere on Stack Exchange, is more complicated (see here) but I'll help with that detailed part, if you supply the link to the source page. TY

IDK why it doesn't recognise that the image is from its own site. It would be a valuable resource if SE developed a libray of images of circuits that people posting could reference as examples.

The basic 555 astable circuit has a minimum duty cycle of > 50%
D1 does not do anything in your circuit but D2 allows a lower duty cycle than 50%.
Essentially the capacitor charges through R1 and discharges through R2, though the diode will have some effect on the timing.
The frequency will be approximately  f = \$\frac {1.44}{C(R1 + R2)}\$
The duty cycle will be approximately R1/(R1+R2)
If you use a 10uF electrolytic capacitor for C, then for 200ms cycle (5Hz) R1+R2 should be 13.89kΩ and therefore for 20% duty cycle R1 should be 2.78kΩ. That leaves 11.1kΩ for R2.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To get 0.5Hz (2 second cycle) with 20% duty cycle, you can increase the electrolytic  capacitor to 100uF and leave the resistors the same.

Ok, I ordered some 1n4148's and will be trying this.
I want to modify the output so that it is controlled by a transistor, do I use a 2N2222A or something else?

The formulas for the high and low time, period, frequency and several other things for a typical xx555 astable oscillator can all be found on page 11 of this datasheet. I don't know how they would work with the circuit you found, you might want to just use a circuit like shown in the datasheet.
The tricky part is that there will be many different combinations of R and C that will yield the same timing results, so you have to come up with reasonable values. Generally you will want to start with a standard value for the capacitance, then calculate the resistor values and either use the closest standard values for those or if you need it to be more precise combine resistors or use a trimmer pot to adjust it.
You want to avoid high value electrolytic capacitors as their leakage and tolerances will throw off the formulas. You also don't want very low values like a few picoFarads as stray capacitances will have more effect. For resistors generally a few hundred ohms to 1 megohm are generally okay. Start with a standard value capacitor, figure out the resistances and if you get very high or very low values for them adjust the capacitance accordingly and recalculate. There's a chart on page 12 of the datasheet that should get you in the ballpark.
UPDATE: Others have noted that the minimum duty cycle for the 555 is greater than 50%, if this is a problem you can invert the output. Say you want the output high 10% of the time, you can find the values for a 90% duty cycle and add an inverter to the output, which could be something like a CMOS inverter or a common emitter transistor circuit. For an astable multivibrator 10% DS is the same as 90% DS flipped upside down.

The standard 555 astable circuit has a minimum "on" (high) output of 50% duty cycle, while you want only 10% or 20%.  So the standard equations do not apply to your application directly.
To do what you want, at least one diode is added to the circuit, so the schematic you posted is partially correct.  Partially, because diode U1 is reverse-biased all the time and has no effect on the circuit.
Side note:  The standard reference designation for a diode is D, not U.  U is used for integrated circuits, so the 555 should be labeled U1.
In the circuit, U2 effectively "shorts out" R2 while C1 is charging up.  Thus, only R1 sets the positive half-cycle period.  This is different from the standard 555 equation, and is complicated by the U2 forward voltage Vf being a small DC offset in the charging circuit.  During the negative half-cycle, C1 is discharged through R2 only.  This is the same as in a standard 555 circuit, so that equation applies directly.
The circuit would be easier to do if the duty cycle were the same percentage for both oscillator frequencies.  In that case, one set of resistor values would work for both frequencies, and only the timing capacitor C1 would have to change.
Again, the schematic you posted will do what you want, but one of the standard equations used for a 555 astable circuit must be modified.
Before we go any farther, please clarify and update up your question.  Your use of the word "pulse" is ambiguous.  What are the two output frequencies you want, and what is the duty cycle for each frequency?
